# When to run my own maven repository?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

I'm working on a small project with one other developer.  We are using libraries that are all available in public maven repositories.  We have a single, multi-module maven project but build all of the modules every time in our build server and developer machines.  The built artifacts are available on the build server for deployment.

Is there any reason for us to setup a maven repository manager?  It would run on the build machine, which I would have to connect to via VPN and is slower than downloading from the internet directly.

Comment: If you decide to have your own, I recommend Artifactory. http://www.jfrog.com/products.php Really easy to set up in either Windows or Linux. You can configure mirrors and backups real easily too.

Comment: I've used archiva and nexus,but never Artifactory.  I'll have a look.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Wondering why the close vote on this?

Comment: Dont recommend artifactory here. It's much slower and much more heavy weight than nexus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best reason to run a repo manager is to achieve reliable behavior in the face of maven's treatment of <repository> declarations.

If any dependency you reference, or plugin you use, or dependency of a plugin you use, declares any repositories, maven will start searching for *everything* in those repositories. And, if they are unreliable or slow, there goes your build. While current policy is to forbid repository declarations in central, there are plenty of historical poms pointing every-which way.

The only cure for this is to set up a repository manager and declare it to be a 'mirrorOf' '*' in settings.xml. Then, put the necessary rules in your repository manager to search only the places you want to search.

Of course, if there are more than one of you and you want to share snapshots or releases, you'll really want a repo manager, too. That's the obvious reason.

If I turn off my repo manager and just try to build some of my projects that have the bad luck to have plugin/dependencies with repository declarations in their poms, they fail. With the repo manager, all is well.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to ask, probably not.
But it's a pretty cheap date - Nexus is pretty trivial to setup, I don't know about archiva.

Public servers tend to be unreliable.
A local mirror will be faster.
You don't want to get hung up because you cleaned your local repo and can't get something off the public one.

If and when you get into needing to work with multiple versions of your app, I'd start thinking about it harder.

Comment: Alright, the multiple versions of my app makes sense, but even with that, since I'm tagging in svn for every release I can easily rebuild the app if needed.  In my case, since the build server is on a mac mini in my buddies basement, it would actually be slower for me to get my artifacts from our local mirror, but a case where a critical dependency is no longer available for some reason is pretty scary.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it only becomes a good reason when the projects and the teams working on them grows more and more, specially because the 'versioning' capabilities of it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is, that you will have to create an own repository as soon as you will need a jar, which is not in the public repositories (not so hard, since for example some JDBC drivers are not hosted in public repo's for licensing issues). If you don't do so, you will loose the main advantage of Maven, that your colleagues do not have to do anything to get the proper libraries. If you introduce a new library, you do not need to say anything to the colleagues if you have company repository, but if not, you need to send the library for them and you need to tell them, how to install the library locally.